# In IntelliJ, how do I do Run with Coverage on a custom scope of tests?

Tags: java, unit-testing, intellij-idea

I have a custom Scope with a bunch of tests included and excluded, and I want to perform Run with Coverage on just these tests. Is there a way to do that?

Answer (score 0):

My current (poor) workaround is to expand all in the test sources folder, and manually shift-click a range of tests and control click off the ones I don't want to run.